# Outputting text before a break in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to run a program that outputs some lines of text and then exits (or at least shows "Press any key to continue) when you input "|". However, when I run this program and input '|', it simply says "Press any key to continue". So it doesn't output the text I want it to.

This is the code I tried to achieve my goal with:

```
if(value == '|')
    {
        cout << lowest << lowest_unit << " is the lowest number.\n";
        cout << highest << highest_unit << " is the highest number. \n";    
        break;
    }
```

If the cause does not lie within the code above, then this is all code of my program:

```
int main()
{ 
 double value;
 double realvalue;
 double lowest = 0;
 double highest = 0; 
 string unit;
 string highest_unit;
 string lowest_unit;
 cout << "Please enter a number follow by a unit: ";

 //convert units to cm for all
 while (cin >>value>>unit)
  {
    if(unit=="cm")
    {
        realvalue = value;
    }
    else if(unit=="in")
    {
        realvalue = value*2.54;
    }
    else if(unit=="m"){
        realvalue = value*100;
    }
    else if(unit=="ft")
    {
        realvalue = value*12*2.54;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Your units are incorrect.\n";
        break;
    }




    if (lowest == 0 && highest == 0)
    {
      lowest = value;
      highest = value;
      lowest_unit = unit;
      highest_unit = unit;
      cout << lowest << highest_unit << " is the smallest so far.\n"
           << highest << lowest_unit <<" is the largest so far.\n";
    }
    else
    {
      if (realvalue < lowest)
      {
        lowest = value;
        lowest_unit = unit;
        cout << value << lowest_unit << " is the smallest so far.\n"
             << highest << highest_unit << " is still the highest.\n";
      }
      else
      {
        if (realvalue > highest)
        {
          highest = value;
          highest_unit = unit;
          cout << lowest << lowest_unit << " is still the lowest.\n"
               << highest << highest_unit << " is the largest so far.\n";
        }
        else
        {
          cout << lowest << lowest_unit << " is still the lowest.\n"
               << highest << highest_unit << " is still the highest.\n";
        }
      }
    }
    cout << "\nPlease enter another number: ";

    if(value == '|')
    {
        cout << lowest << lowest_unit << " is the lowest number.\n";
        cout << highest << highest_unit << " is the highest number. \n";    
        break;
    }

  }
}
```

(what it basically does is compares different lengths the user inputs, and then decides which length is the smallest and which is the largest which the user has inputted).

How can I achieve my goal of outputting the text before (or more accurately, while) "Press any key to continue" is shown?

Comment: Be careful for floating-point aritimetic errors. Using `==` for compareing floating-point values may not be good due to errors. Did you check the value of `value`?

Comment: You can have the text be printed by inputting `124 cm` if ASCII code is used in your system.

Answer (score 0):

`value` is a double. When you type |, it won't be read as a number, and `value` won't be set. Instead, a failure bit should be set in cin.

Comparing `value == '|'` checks to see if `value` equals the numeric value of the ASCII character |, which happens to be 124—that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your program expects two inputs, everytime, in your loop.

If you want to stop at the first input, then you need to read the input in two steps.

Also, your `value` is a number, not a string, you can't read numbers and strings the same way.

```
while (1) {
    string tmp;
    if (!(cin >> tmp)) {
        break;
    }

    if (tmp == "|") {
        break;
    }

    //convert string into double
    value = stod(tmp); //todo, check conversion was well done

    if (! (cin >> unit) ) {
        break;
    }

    // rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`"|"` is not what can be interpreted as `double`, so you should use `std::string` to read the input.

Your code should be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::stod;
using std::string;

int main()
{ 
  double value;
  double realvalue;
  double lowest = 0;
  double highest = 0;
  string value_str;
  string unit;
  string highest_unit;
  string lowest_unit;
  cout << "Please enter a number follow by a unit: ";

  //convert units to cm for all
  while (cin >>value_str>>unit)
  {
    if (value_str == "|") // use string literal, not character constant
    {
       cout << lowest << lowest_unit << " is the lowest number.\n";
       cout << highest << highest_unit << " is the highest number. \n";
       break;
    }
    value = stod(value_str);

    // do works with value and unit
    cout << value << "\t" << unit << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: still will need to input something like `| <...>` to actually quit